# How to call constructor with 2 arguments from a no argument constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, default-constructor

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this one. I have 2 constructors. The first has 2 arguments:

```
public Instrument(string name, string category)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Category = category;
}
```

Then I have a default(no argument) constructor with constants for defaults:

```
public Instrument()            
{
    this.Name = DefaultName;
    this.Category = DefaultCategory;
}
```

I am also supposed to call the 2 parameter constructor from the no argument constructor. How do I do this? I also question why this is even necessary. If you are calling the 2 parameter from the default how would you ever pass the default values to the application?  So I guess my main question is how do I call the 2 parameter constructor from the default constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by calling the two arg constructor from the default one, passing the default values, like this:

```
public Instrument() : this(DefaultName, DefaultCategory)
{

}
```

Comment: In regard to passing defaults into the default constructor: the intent is generally to simplify use of class by providing the default values via a constant built-in by the class / library author.  Thus the client seeking to use the defaults would simply call the constructor without arguments, this gaining the intended benefit of not having to provide the 2 arguments except when she or he needed to override the defaults.

Comment: So in the above the "this" portion is calling the 2 argument constructor? But it is only to pass the defaults? Perhaps I have been over thinking this. My head is saying if you call the 2 argument constructor, you will get the 2 arguments and not the defaults.

Comment: yes, this keyword refers to the current class, so `this(arg1, arg2)` calls the constructor, passing the default values. it's basically the same as if the user called the 2 argument constructor passing default information, just the user doesn't have to if they want default information

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do this...

```
public class Instrument
{
    public string Name;
    public string Category;

    public Instrument()
        : this("DefaultName", "DefaultCategory")
    {

    }

    public Instrument(string name, string category)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Category = category;
    }
}
```

Now to answer the question *why this is even necessary.*...

This is to make sure that if you ever come across an instantiated object inside the code - doesn't matter how it was instantiated (using either of constructor) - it will always have valid values in it's properties **Name** & **Category**.

Basically, it potentially makes your business objects bug free. Anyone using your business object will always have valid values in it's properties - either default or passed in using 2nd constructor.